# Correct usage of applying character limit validations in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now I'm following the Michael Hartl's Rails Guide but ran into an issue in the second chapter when applying a character limit validation:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :content, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

I tried to use an alternative approach but the validation didn't take effect. Any idea on how to get this to work?

```
validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 140
```

Comment: Both are valid.No idea why it is not working for you.Did you got any error?

Comment: What is the datatype of `content`?

Comment: I mean its string or integer or anythingelse?

Comment: I defined it as a string

Comment: I'm not getting an error. Its just allowing me to post anything regardless the length.

Comment: Probably you are giving less than 140 characters.Do check once again.

Comment: It looks like I had to exceed the 140 character limit for it to work. I guess my question should've have been how to create a mix of maximum/minimum where the user must enter a minimum of say 5 characters but a max of 140

Comment: Yes! `maximum:140` refers to the allowed length up to 140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment below the question

If you want to put range validation on length following should do

```
validates :content, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 140}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this way too

```
validates :content, length: { in: 6..20 } #minimum=> 6 and maximum=>20
```

OR

```
validates_length_of :content, :in => 6..20 #minimum=> 6 and maximum=>20
```